# how to check record is created from previous three month

Tags: laravel

how can i check the remarks against users is created in last three month Using laravel . i have one to many relationship user and remarks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Xrp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just Simple,

```
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $lastThreeMonth = $now->copy()->subDay(30 + 30 + 30); // 3 months

        $query = Model::whereHas('relation', function (Builder $q) use ($lastThreeMonth, $now) {
            $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$lastThreeMonth, $now]);
        });

        $result = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal Ribdiya

Comment: Hope it is usefull for you !! @Waleed

Comment: Change the multiply(*) to add(+) in the subDay() i.e
$lastThreeMonth = $now->copy()->subDay(30 + 30 + 30); // 3 months
or better still
$lastThreeMonth = $now->copy()->subDay(90); // 3 months